# How do I use lappy to find means of a list of vectors while wanting to na.rm=TRUE

Tags: r, lapply

So, Say I have

```
l <- list(a=c(1, 2, NA), b=c( 2, 3, NA), c=c(5, NA, 6))
lapply(l, mean)
```

How do I use lapply where I want the mean function to use the parameter na.rm=TRUE

The following is not working

```
lapply(l, mean(na.rm=TRUE))
```

Thanks.

Comment: `lapply(1, mean, na.rm = TRUE)`?

Comment: $Ananda Mahto -- sorry about that -- that was a mistake -- corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can use the `...` to pass other arguments to your function, so the following should work:

```
l <- list(a=c(1, 2, NA), b=c( 2, 3, NA), c=c(5, NA, 6))
lapply(l, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

In some cases, it might be easier to use an anonymous function, like this:

```
lapply(l, function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

In the second case above, that would be similar to doing something like:

1. Defining a new `mean` function preset with `na.rm = TRUE`:

   ```
   meanNArm <- function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
   ```
2. Using that function in `lapply`:

   ```
   lapply(l, meanNArm)
   ```

If the function you were dealing with were quite complex, or if you had to do this regularly, then defining your own function might make sense, otherwise, a simple anonymous function (or passing the relevant argument with `...`) would be the more logical approach.

Comment: @user1172468 - because the whole `function(x)...` bit defines a complete function applied to the data. The same reason why `{function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)}(c(NA,1,2))` works.